# Bootstrap tab is starting with big Whitespace in Secondtab

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a form which is in many tabs like tab1, tab2, tab3. It just bunch of inputs form. I want to submit all the form content as one. But the problem is my second tab is starting from where the first form stops. So I have huge black space at top of second tab. I have attached the JSfiddle link below. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
<h1>
  My Heading
</h1>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#info1" data-toggle="tab">Info 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#info2" data-toggle="tab">Info 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel-body no-padding">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <form action="ACTION URL" method="PUT" id="idforthis" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div id="info1" class="tab-pane fade active in">  
<fieldset>
  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <label class="input">Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <label class="input">Age
        <input type="text" name="" value="">
      </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <label class="input">Sex
        <input type="text" name="address1" value="">
      </label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <label class="input">Location
        <input type="text" name="address2" value="">
      </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <label class="input">City
        <input type="text" name="city" value="">
      </label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <label class="input">State
        <input type="text" name="state" value="">
      </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="info2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <fieldset>
  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <label class="input">Input 1 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <label class="input">Input 2 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <label class="input">Input 3 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <label class="input">Input 3 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <section>
      <label class="input">Input 4 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </section>
    <section>
      <label class="input">Last Input
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
  <footer>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </footer>
</form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle for Bootstrap tab form](https://jsfiddle.net/ae99k90p/4/)

Answer (score 4):

Here the problem is with the css. In bootstrap the css for tab is written as

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
```

here `.tab-pane` should be `direct child` (In your case it is `form`)
Inorder to solve you issue You should change ur css in bootstrap or you have to write in your custom.css like below :

```
.tab-content .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content  .active {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by your use of `fade` and `in` on the `tab-pane`s.

If you remove those and also reposition your `form` tag so that it is not an element inside `tab-content` then I think this is the result you are looking for.

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#info1" data-toggle="tab">Info 1</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#info2" data-toggle="tab">Info 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panel-body no-padding">
      <form action="ACTION URL" method="PUT" id="idforthis" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="info1" class="tab-pane active">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="col col-sm-4">
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Age
        <input type="text" name="" value="">
      </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-sm-4">
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Sex
        <input type="text" name="address1" value="">
      </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Location
        <input type="text" name="address2" value="">
      </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-sm-4">
                <section>
                  <label class="input">City
        <input type="text" name="city" value="">
      </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="input">State
        <input type="text" name="state" value="">
      </label>
                </section>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div id="info2" class="tab-pane">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="col col-sm-4">
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Input 1 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Input 2 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-sm-4">
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Input 3 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Input 3 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-sm-4">
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Input 4 tab 2
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <label class="input">Last Input
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
                </section>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <footer>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </footer>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ae99k90p/14/)

Answer (score 0):

The content of tab1 is actually in tab2, it's just invisible - as you probably know from your question. On tab1, the content of tab2 is there too - meaning, you can see the space for it at the bottom.

Are you using the Javascript library needed for this to work?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

> Using navs for tab panels requires JavaScript tabs plugin For tabs
>   with tabbable areas, you must use the tabs JavaScript plugin. The
>   markup will also require additional role and ARIA attributes – see the
>   plugin's example markup for further details.

and that links to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs

Are you customizing any CSS or following Bootstrap to the T to test this?